# Why my frame of my uiimageview is not updated?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, frame

I have an `IBOutlet` imageProfile (`UIImageView`).
When I set a frame in my code, my `UIImageView` frame is not updated but my layer is updated,
Can you tell me why ?

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageProfile: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    setDesign()

 }

func setDesign() {
        var newFrame=imageProfile.frame
    newFrame.origin.x=50
    newFrame.origin.y=100
    newFrame.size.width=150
    newFrame.size.height=150
    imageProfile.frame=newFrame
    imageProfile.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    imageProfile.backgroundColor=UIColor.blackColor()
    imageProfile.layer.cornerRadius = 75
    imageProfile.layer.borderWidth=3
    imageProfile.clipsToBounds = true
    imageProfile.updateConstraints()


}
```

If i delete the `IBOutlet` and try this, my frame is updated :

```
var imageProfile: UIImageView?
override func viewDidLoad() {

super.viewDidLoad()
setDesign()

}
  func setDesign() {
    var image: UIImage = UIImage(named: "iconSuggestSelect.png")!
    imageProfile = UIImageView(image: image)
    imageProfile!.frame = CGRectMake(100,100,100,200)
    imageProfile!.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    imageProfile!.backgroundColor=UIColor.blackColor()
    imageProfile!.layer.cornerRadius = 75
    imageProfile!.layer.borderWidth=3
    imageProfile!.clipsToBounds = true
    imageProfile!.updateConstraints()
    imageCover.addSubview(imageProfile!)
```

}

Comment: Are you using this on viewDidLoad ?

Comment: Yes, i'm using it in a function called in viewDidLoad !

Comment: Update your viewController Code

Comment: can you also provide the current screenshot and the wanted screen?
Are you sure that the variable "myView" has a frame? From where comes imageCover? i suggest setting static values at first before using them from the other views. so set the origin.x and origin.y to 200 or something like that. Than you can check if its a problem of the frame from the Views or on the update itself.

Comment: I try with static values and it doesn't work !

Comment: is the imageView aligned with constraints? if yes, than you have to call imageProfile.updateConstraints()

Comment: i removed my answer, lets debug here in the comments :) ... you could also provide more informations about your views, storyboard, screenshots :) would be a great help

Comment: i don't have constraints on my image view but i have contraints in my view controller, i try updateConstraints on my imageView but it doesn't work again

Comment: I try to delete all the constraints and it doesn't work too

Comment: if you have constraints in your view, than you should set also constraints to you image and change the constraints insteed. if you want to show this in the center of the view, just set center.x and center.y to the superview for example. Layer will move because its the lower level of changing the elements. It has more power over the rest :)

Comment: I try to delete all the constraints in my view controller and it doesn't work too

Comment: Updated again my answer , any progress ?

Comment: No progress, i try your answer updated,it doesn't work